# How to import a scss file from a node module into an Angular 10 application?

Tags: angular, node-modules

I want to import a stylesheet from an external node module ('_base.scss') into an Angular application.

[image]

I have tried importing the module into the global style like so:

**styles.scss**

```
@import '~codyhouse-framework/main/assets/css/_base';
```

After researching similar questions on here, still no luck. I have also tried:

- importing the stylesheet into the components style array with viewEncapsulation set to 'none'
- adding the stylesheet to the angular.json 'styles' array

Still no luck. Any idea on the correct steps to implement this?

The node module is from 'cody-framework'. Here is a link to its documentation https://codyhouse.co/ds/docs/framework

Comment: How do you know it's not being imported?

Comment: did you also tried importing with relative path? (`nodemodules/.../...`)

Comment: here is what docs says: `@import '../node_modules/codyhouse-framework/main/assets/css/base';` (supposing that your on src root folder, so that nodemodules is the parent folder)

Comment: yes i've tried this, but the documentation doesn't explicitly mention where this should be imported in an angular application